# retrieve selected radio button value in a image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I want to display radio button values as per user selection but while alert i didn't get the values.
I also want to display radio button values as a Image.. like when user select Male then Male pic shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test">
<h4>Gender</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <h4>Occupation</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="PvtJob">Pvt. Job<br>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="Govt">Govt. Employee<br>
  <h4>Loan Type</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Personal">Personal Loan<br>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Health">Health Loan<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right place-order-button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return myFunction()" type="submit" >Finish</button>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var radioButtons =["gender","occupation","loan"];

        for( var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
            if ($('input[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked','#test').val()) {
                alert("You checked " + $('input[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked','#test').attr('id'));
                alert("Value is " + $('input[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked','#test').val());
        }
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: is this required on button click or radio button click?

Comment: And i think you if condition is incorrect.

Comment: You need to add reference to jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery in your code and there is snot attribute id mentioned in your input. Also no id such as test is present in your code. 
You also don't need to repeat the selector again, you can simple use `$(this)`

Try the below snippet.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var radioButtons =["gender","occupation","loan"];

        for( var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
            if ($('input[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked').val()) {
                alert("Value is " + $(this).val());
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<form id="test">
<h4>Gender</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <h4>Occupation</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="PvtJob">Pvt. Job<br>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="Govt">Govt. Employee<br>
  <h4>Loan Type</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Personal">Personal Loan<br>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Health">Health Loan<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right place-order-button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return myFunction()" type="submit" >Finish</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery functionalities, you need add Jquery library in your header. Please add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in to header section and try

Answer (score 0):

you can check selected element using `length` proprty of object. also **add jquery library path** in your HTML page.

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var radioButtons =["gender","occupation","loan"];

        for( var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
            selected=$('input[name = "'+radioButtons[x]+'"]:checked','#test');
            if (selected.length>0) {
              
                alert(radioButtons[x] + "::  Value is " + selected.val());
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
<h4>Gender</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id=""> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <h4>Occupation</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="PvtJob">Pvt. Job<br>
  <input type="radio" name="occupation" value="Govt">Govt. Employee<br>
  <h4>Loan Type</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Personal">Personal Loan<br>
  <input type="radio" name="loan" value="Health">Health Loan<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right place-order-button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return myFunction()" type="submit" >Finish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you are going on right way.. but i want to display selected values as an image in a div like select male then it show men pic not male .. thanks in advance.